# XSLT - remove duplicate namespace declarations

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml:

```
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="xmldsig">
  <ds:SignedInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  </ds:SignedInfo>
  <ds:SignedInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
     <ds:SignedInfoData xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
  </ds:SignedInfo/>
</ds:Signature>
```

The problem is, while I need the first `ds` namespace declaration in `<ds:Signature>`. the following ones (in `<ds:SignedInfo>` and `<ds:SignedInfoData>`) are not required. Is there any way to remove duplicate namespace declarations using XSLT 1.0 to get this output:

```
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="xmldsig">
  <ds:SignedInfo>
  </ds:SignedInfo>
  <ds:SignedInfo>
     <ds:SignedInfoData/>
  </ds:SignedInfo>
</ds:Signature>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eliminating the duplicated namespace declarations is something that happens by just copying the input, for instance with an identity transformation http://xsltransform.net/jxDigU1/1

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Or simpler still `<xsl:template match="/"><xsl:copy-of select="."/></xsl:template>`